# Output CSV as a single string in bash without extra installations

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file that contains data like so:

```
1, 2, 3
A, B, C
4, 5, 6
```

I'm trying to output this in bash as a single string separated by newlines like so:

`"1, 2, 3\nA, B, C\n4, 5, 6"`

I tried numerous ways but nothing has worked yet.  Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Based on answers provided, since other users of my code might need the same transformation and I can't guarantee what's on their system, still looking for answers independent of whether or not I have:

1. GNU sed installed
2. Windows line endings or not
3. Have `dos2unix` installed

Comment: Since I can't even answer my own question... here's what ultimately worked for me: `var=$(tr '\r\n' '\\n' < input.csv)` Then `echo "$var:q" > output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure whether you want to use your expected output in bash or want to use the specified output somewhere else. Here are two answers for both cases:

## Replacing newlines with `\n` and add surrounding `"` quotes

In this case your question is a duplicate – at least the part of replacing newlines with literal `\n`s. The easiest solution is 
`sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g;s/.*/"&"/' yourFile` provided that you have GNU `sed`.
If your file ends with a newline (as text files usually do) so will your string:
`"1, 2, 3\nA, B, C\n4, 5, 6\n"`

If you don't want that trailing `\n` you can exclude it before the actual processing:

```
sed -z 's/\n$//;s/\n/\\n/g;s/.*/"&"/' yourFile
"1, 2, 3\nA, B, C\n4, 5, 6"
```

## Encode a multi-line file in a single-line bash string

Use bash's built-in `printf` with the `%q` format. From `help printpf`:

> `%q` quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input

To pass the file content to printf use a subshell:

```
printf %q "$(< yourFile)"
```

This will use bash's C-string format since `\n` is *not* treated as a newline in double quoted `"..."` strings:

```
$'1, 2, 3\nA, B, C\n4, 5, 6'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the first option gave me `sed: illegal option -- z` and the second option gave me `1,2,3$'\r'$'\n'A,B,C$'\r'$'\n'4,5,6%`.  Sorry I don't quite understand!

Comment: The error shows that you don't have GNU sed but another version instead. The second output shows that your file does not use linux line endings `\n` but windows line endings `\r\n`. Convert your file to linux line endings (use the `dos2unix` tool) and then use the marked duplicate to replace `\n` with `\\n` **or** use `sed 's/\r/\\n/' yourFile | tr -d '\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

[Both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) of [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters) questions take exactly the same approach to accomplish this task.

It should just be a matter of swapping the "," out for a literal "\n", which you can do with `\\n`

EDIT: In the event the links go dead, the relevant solution from the previous answers is below. Full credit to [Zsolt Botykai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11621/zsolt-botykai) for this answer, which I've modified for your specific use case:

> Use this solution with GNU sed:
>
> `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' file`
>
> This will read the whole file in a loop,
>   then replaces the newline(s) with a space.
>
> Explanation:
>
> 1. Create a label via `:a`.
> 2. Append the current and next line to the pattern
>      space via `N`.
> 3. If we are before the last line, branch to the created
>      label `$!ba` (`$!` means not to do it on the last line as there should be
>      one final newline).
> 4. Finally the substitution replaces every newline
>      with a space on the pattern space (which is the whole file).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24660543)

Comment: Excellent point, thanks for pointing this out @shalomb! I've modified my answer to include the relevant parts of the answer from the provided links.

Comment: @DavidAllewell unfortunately this just gave me the exact same output as the table I originally had.

Comment: @Frankie Really? I get the requested result. Can you show a terminal output? What version of Bash are you using (I'm presuming Bash). Are there any carriage returns in the CSV file, perhaps?